# Facebook iOS SDK returns to application

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I integrated facebook login to my application, but Apple rejected the application, because there were some logic issues.

I figured out that when user re-installs the application, he needs to login via facebook again. Unfortunately, when user tries to login again, facebook SDK just returns to the application! Even worse: Facebook active session state is not opened, and when trying to open new session completion handler block is not called!

It's really annoying. Maybe you had same problem and can help me?

Comment: "when user re-installs the application, he needs to login via facebook again."
Isn't this normal behaviour ?

Comment: It's a normal behavior. Although, Facebook SDK does not give the user ability to login (it has saved token or something like this). It just transit the screen to facebook app or safari, show white screen and comes back to application with no callbacks called. That is strange, I think